# MySql JOIN three tables and calculate the percentage of all the given month

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a three tables, users, reports and fees

fees: We charge some amount of fees based on the month, so it can be different in each month.

[image]

We have to calculate total sum of each user revenue and also deduct the fees from the sum.

As of now I'm only be able to calculate the Total SUM but not with deduction

```
select users.content_provider as Vendor_name, 
       reports.content_provider as vendor_id,
       FORMAT(SUM(reports.total_rev),2) as vendor_earned_amount
from reports 
inner join users
    ON users.id = reports.content_provider
WHERE reports.year BETWEEN 2016 AND 2017
  AND reports.month BETWEEN 01 AND 06
GROUP BY reports.content_provider
```

We can range the month and year. I don't understand how i can loop through each rows and calculate the SUM, Please Help

Result of my query.

[image]

Comment: This looks more like a spreadsheet than a table. Consider revising your schema.

Comment: BTW your sample data and your output are different. If you could share the expected result set by editing your post and change the image to text.

Comment: You mention three tables, but I only see one.  I'm confused.  Is that the results you want?  Is that what one of the tables looks like?  Your question is unclear.